# Perl Script – Look at the first number of each line and alert if 0 exists

Tags: regex, perl

Currently the script only looks at the first character of a txt file and emails if that value =0 using regex. I'm trying to update the script so it looks at each line until the end of the file and alert of any of the lines have the number 0. If all lines have 1 then do nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example of an alert

```
1
1
1
0 -since there is a 0 an email alert would be generated 
1
1
```

code below:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = '/users/tneal01/SPOOL/output.txt';
my $mark = 0;


my $cont = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file -- $!";
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

# Pull the first number
my ($num) = $cont =~ /^(\d+)/;

if ($num == $mark)
{
    my $body = "status $num has been recorded ";
    my $cmd_email = "echo $body | " .
        "mailx -s \"error occurring\" tneal01\@gmail.com";
    system($cmd_email) == 0  or die "Error sending email -- $!";
}
```

Comment: Your program seems a fair start, although it's usually unnecessary to read the whole file into memory, and can make coding more awkward. What is your question?

Comment: If you're looking *only* for appearances of `$match` at the start of a line then I suggest that you write just `if ( $cont =~ /^$match\b/m ) { # send email )`

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably go with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file   = '/users/tneal01/SPOOL/output.txt';
my $mark   = '0';
my $search = qr/^$mark\b/;


open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file -- $!";

while (<$fh>) {

   #line starts with 0. Or check other regex.
   if (m/$search/) {
      my $body = "status $mark has been recorded ";
      my $cmd_email =
        "echo $body | " . "mailx -s \"error occurring\" tneal01\@gmail.com";
      system($cmd_email) == 0 or die "Error sending email -- $!";

     #bail out the loop - assume you don't want more than one email per thing.
      last;
   }
}

close ( $fh );
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution only reads one line at a time... there are simple solutions, but would need to load the entire file into memory...
I'm also assuming you want to know how many occurencies of $mark there are in the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $file = 'file.txt';
my $mark = '0';

open my $f, "<$file" or die "Error open file: $!\n";
my $counter=0;
while(my $line = <$f>) {
  if($line =~ /$mark/) {
    $counter++;
  }
}
if($counter) {
    my $body = "status $mark has been recorded $counter times";
    my $cmd_email = "echo $body | mailx -s \"error occurring\" tneal01\@gmail.com";
    system($cmd_email) == 0  or die "Error sending email -- $!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sergio! I like addition of the counter times!

Answer (score 0):

This does a couple of things differently to other solutions here.

1. It reads from whatever filename is given on the command line
2. It stops checking once the first error is found

I don't know how useful those improvements are to you.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $mark = 0;

while (<>) {
  my ($num) = /^(\d)/;
  if ($num == $mark) {
    my $body = "status $num has been recorded ";
    my $cmd_email = "echo $body | " .
        'mailx -s "error occurring" tneal01\@gmail.com';
    system($cmd_email) == 0  or die "Error sending email -- $!";
    last; # stop checking after the first error
  }
}
```

(Oh, and I switched some double-quotes to single-quotes so you don't have to escape embedded double quotes.)

Comment: If you find answers to be useful, please consider upvoting them and accepting one.

Answer (score 0):

This version uses minimal changes to your existing script. I've commented the changes.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = '/users/tneal01/SPOOL/output.txt';
my $mark = 0;


my $cont = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file -- $!";
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

# Pull the first number            <-- comment not needed
# my ($num) = $cont =~ /^(\d+)/; # <-- delete this line

if ($cont =~ /^$mark/m)     # <-- change the condition to this regex
{
    my $body = "status $mark has been recorded "; # replace $num with $mark
    my $cmd_email = "echo $body | " .
        "mailx -s \"error occurring\" tneal01\@gmail.com";
    system($cmd_email) == 0  or die "Error sending email -- $!";
}
```

What the change does is use a regular expression to check if any lines begin with the value defined in `$mark`.

I deleted the `$num` variable, but its contents was the same as `$mark` so we can just use `$mark` instead.

A breakdown of `$cont =~ /^$mark/m`:

- `$cont =~` Apply the following regex to the string contained in `$cont`
- `/` Start the regular expression
- `^` Match the beginning of a line
- `$mark` Match the string specified in the $mark variable
- `/` End regular expression
- `m` Flag to tell the regex to treat `$cont` as a multiple-line string (which it is)

Comment: Thank you Adam, I how you included the breakdown!

Comment: No problem. You could up-vote the answers you found useful, and accept the answer you used. We like that because we get points. :-)